# How to sort order of "Posts", "Files", and "Notes" in a channel in Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I need to create a channel in a Team where it is sorted as "Notes", "Files", then "Posts", but it is in reverse order by default, and I can't find a way to change it. I need users to see the instructions found in Notes first, as soon as they click on the channel. How can these be sorted like this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it isn't possible to change those settings in Teams nor am I aware of anything on the roadmap to allow you to do so.

I would suggest posting this on the [Teams Uservoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) although if you search on Uservoice for 'reorder tabs', you'll find open requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you are providing a link to others, you could provide a direct link to say the Notes tab (just copy URL when on the tab).

Answer (score 0):

You might be happy with a pinned post in the channel. Unfortunately not available yet, but there is an already high voted idea on Uservoice:

https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/16911532-ability-to-pin-message-files-articles-shared-withi